# Router setup for cable net connection

Tags: wireless-router, cable-modem

Cable connections are now very popular in India. Companies like Meghbela, Allience are providing internet connection through cable. To access internet user need to open a authentication web page from local operator's server and after proving userid/password user can access internet. That authentication page need to keep open all the time user is surfing and user need to logout at the end. That authentication page continuously refreshes itself to keep the connection alive.

My query is can I configure my old DIR-300 router so that it will automatically open the authentication page and then will put userid/password opening the authentication page.

If my DIR-300 is not capable for it then do I have any other options?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible using your router, but you can invest in something like the [Raspberry Pi](http://raspberrypi.org) which you'd keep running all the time and it would keep the authentication page active. Leaving a Raspberry Pi on for an entire year would cost a few USD, so it's affordable I guess.

I am not sure how this login system works but I guess it will keep the connection active for your entire LAN, if that's not the case you could set a PC/Raspberry Pi up to keep the page running and then route all of your connections through this computer, but that would be way more complicated.

Comment: Do I have to login every time with Raspberry Pi or it will remember and login automatically every time I login?